# With thruput known, how determine number of threads in Thread Group in a JMeter test

Tags: jmeter

I am told to set Constant Thruput as 25 rps for 1 hr duration of test. I am not given any info on number of Threads. I have to determine it. How do I decide on number of users/Threads in UI? In existing tests, I see number of threads as 25 times 2. It is double as prod is assumed to be scaled twice to non prod and pre prod. My tests run on pre prod or non prod.

I ran its Jenkins job with various rps and various number of threads to see what is transaction per second in HTML report and what is OK and KO percentage. I find that best OK% and transaction per sec, I get at 25 or 50 threads in tests.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I decide on number of users/Threads in UI?

it depends on your system under test response time. If it's 1 second - go for 25 users. If it's 2 seconds - go for 50 users, etc. It also worth adding some extra "spare" threads on top. See [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) article for more details.

Alternatively you can consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination, given you connect them via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) the timer will be able to kick off extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient for conducting the required load.

> It is double as prod is assumed to be scaled twice to non prod and pre prod

I don't think your assumption is correct, given "prod" has 2x more resources than "nonprod" it doesn't mean that it will handle 2x load, it doesn't extrapolate this way. You cannot run a performance test against a scaled down environment and predict the performance in a production one. The environments must be exactly the same.